# Newton's method for the brachistochrone

Tags: real-analysis, calculus-of-variations, classical-mechanics

Consider the potential $V(x,y)=-y$ and a particle at rest in the beginning of the coordinate system. We are going to examine the brachistochrone - the smooth curve of fastest descent. Assume we are aiming at the point $(1,1)$. Assume the smooth curve of interest has parametric equations $(x(t),y(t))$. Then the curve has continuous derivatives in its parametric interval and $\dot x^2+\dot y^2\not=0$. Without further due, the notes I am reading claim that under our assumption for smoothness a unique implicit function $y(x)$ exists and $y_x>0$.

Our physical intuition agrees with those claims. How can we see analytically that indeed an implicit function $y(x)$ exist and not $x(y)$, and that the derivative $y_x>0$? In case additional assumptions are needed which would be the minimal set of sufficient additional assumptions?

**p.s.** I can give more details from the notes but I believe I have considered all the relevant assumptions.

Comment: The $y$-axis of our coordinate system points towards the center of the earth (towards the source of the potential). Since space is isotropic, the laws of physics are invariant under rotations. This allows us to choose such a coordinate system. @mvw

Comment: Actually I am not sure. I would love to hear what a cosmologist would say. The classical invariants that give the conservation of energy, momentum, angular momentum, what happens to them in expanding/shrinking/changing space?

Comment: For the purpose of this post assume all the classical invariants, conservation laws, Euler-Lagrange's theorem, etc.

Comment: What is written does not justify the conclusion about existence of $y(x)$. The author must have made an  assumption that the path will be of this particular form (for the sake of simplifying analysis), and neglected to state this assumption.

Comment: Thank you, sir. What about positivity of the derivative, does that follow from considering the given potential and endpoints? @Thisismuchhealthier.

Comment: No, it does not follow either. Conceivably, the graph of $y$ could be flat in places or even drop down sometimes. Of course, we would not the fastest descent curve to do that. This is why, instead of laboring through the general parametric form, it's easier to restrict to "realistic" curves and seek minimal time within that class.